# WCF IsReference = true is resetting the values to Default

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have a very simple WCF 4.0 service in which I am returning an POCO entity object whose IsReference is set to true. When I return the object from my service, the values of primitive types (int, double, etc) are set correctly and the ones having references are also getting serialized properly, I've verified that the serialization happen correctly putting following code just before return statement. I've also verified that the members are correctly marked with [DataMember] and they have public getters/setters. However, when the object is received by the caller, all the primitive types are set to 0 and the ones with references are set to NULL.

Would appreciate any help!

```
try
       {
           var stream = new MemoryStream();
           var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(onlineSellItemDetail.GetType());

           dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(stream, onlineSellItemDetail);


       }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString()); 
       }
```

Comment: `DataContractSerializer` constructor has an overload with a flag that allows cyclic references if we're talking .NET Framework and not SL, maybe ought to check that out

Answer (score 0):

This is almost always because no XML, empty XML, or incompatible XML was received on the client end. Sometimes, this is because the stream was not flushed or closed properly on the service side. Other times, the client side is operating with completely valid XML in its own stream, but is reading the XML by perhaps not starting at the beginning of the stream. If you enable tracing on the service side and the client side, generate tracing logs, and analyze with SvcTraceViewer, and in parallel, use Fiddler to monitor the wire traffic on both the client side and the service side, I think you'll find the answer for sure!